# How do I save downloaded files to my app for later use?

Tags: android, file, sqlite, download

My app uses an API to save data to a database. Part of that data will include a url to files (pdf, images, and videos). I'm doing this api request through an AsyncTask already.

My plan is to use the provided url from the api -> save the files locally -> store their location in the database.

This way I can can call up a list of pdf documents based on a set of SQLite parameters, get the file info, create a list of files, and allow the user to view a pdf (or image... or video...) by selecting it.

I have everything working but not sure how to

1. Pull down the files from the url
2. save files locally
3. save the currently saved file location to the database

I know this is a big ask and I'm more looking for good resources on how to achieve this. There are quite a few resources but picking through the best option is overwhelming.

Thanks!

----- edit -----

Error I'm getting after using Zygote's answer:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/library/2/invester-service.jpg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:416)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:88)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:73)
    at com.myBooks.library.BooksDB$1.run(BooksDB.java:812)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
    at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:110)
    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:400)
```

I can see that line 812 is being called out in the error (showing 809-812):

```
File file = new File(SDCardRoot + "/library/"+file_type,file_name);

//this will be used to write the downloaded data into the file we created
FileOutputStream fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(file);
```

I've added code to create the directory (per Zygote' suggestion) but I'm getting the same error. mkdir is failing and the storage state shows a mounted when ran:

```
File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/library/"+file_type);
String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
//create a new file, specifying the path, and the filename
//which we want to save the file as.

boolean success = true;
if (!folder.exists()) {
    success = folder.mkdir();
    Log.d("storage state",state);
}
if (success) {
    // Do something on success
    Log.d("success","made it");
} else {
    // Do something else on failure 
    Log.d("success","didn't made it");
}
```

Comment: you probably need to create the directories structure first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its actually fairly simple. You can accomplish 1 and 2 by simply using HttpURLConnection and Input and output streams to download the file and save it anywhere you'd like. Then simply add a method to your database class to store the location you saved the file to in your database.

I wrote a very simple file downloading app a while back which includes all the code you need for task one and two. Its a bit too much to copy/paste in here, so Ill just send you the GitHub source link. Check out line 102 and below [here](https://github.com/Untouchab1e/WhereToGo/blob/master/android_wheretogo/src/com/connectutb/wheretogo/DownloadDialog.java)

Remember that network code should never be run on your GUI thread!

Good luck!

Comment: wow! thanks! I'll check it out and see how it works for me. If all goes well I'll select this as an answer. And Yes, I'm running all my api and network calls via an AsyncTask outside the GUI during a a splash screen.

Comment: Sounds good! Let me know how it works out, or if you have any other questions.

Comment: I'm getting a "FileNotFoundException" and an "open failed" error on all my files. I tried using the myprogress to see how things were going but "context" in the ProgressDialog initialization seems to be causing a NullPointerException error.

Comment: I've updated my question to show the error and where the error is being called.

Comment: I think you need to make sure that /storage/emulated/0/library/2/ exists, as I dont believe it will automatically create the necessary directories, if that makes sense. So check if the directory exists first?

Comment: ah! good point! I'm trying to do that now but it won't make the directory. Could the issue be it trying to create in "/storage/emulated"?

Comment: I've checked the storage state and it shows to be mounted and I have my permissions set in the manifest.

Comment: Ok, I realized I was making "/library/" and "/x/" at the same time. If I make one then the other the directories show "made it" but the files still show they don't exist.

Comment: well, do the directories actually exist? Check your /sdcard partition and see if the necessary folders are there.

Comment: never mind I had a error making the second directory. I have a new issue, but it seems to be a goof on the api admin. some files have a space in them such as, "http://api-site.com/file/sample doc 1.pdf". Obviously this isn't good as the code will see the url as "http://api-site.com/file/sample". The other files without spaces didn't throw any errors.